# What adjective did The Economist use to describe Andrew Lloyd Webber's music?

Tags: media

Years ago I remember reading in [The Economist](http://www.economist.com) newspaper a particularly poignant adjective used to describe Andrew Lloyd Webber's music. Unfortunately, I have forgotten the exact term. I haven't been able to find it using internet search mechanisms. Does anyone remember the term?

Comment: Can you give more context, for example, how many years ago, and what musical of ALW's was current at the time ? or what other events were current then ?

Comment: I remember reading it in the print edition, so it must have been sometime between 1995 and 2015.  Unfortunately, I cannot remember more details, other than the poignancy: it was something like "schmaltzy" or "Wagnerian", but more hard-hitting.

Comment: You could maybe contact The Economist to see if they have an archive.

Comment: All these editions are available online.

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to locate any particularly poignant adjective used by The Economist. The most regrettable statement that I could [locate](https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2001/12/06/cerebral-and-sentimental) was:

> Yet ever since he started writing the soaring tunes which have became his trademark, he has been dogged by accusations of plagiarism.

The "Wagnerian" adjective was used by [The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/rock-opera-um-no-1168208.html):

> There's a reservoir of one or two tunes that flow ad nauseam, and I guess Lloyd Webber would defend the repetitions as Leitmotifs - adopting the Wagnerian system of associating a musical idea with a specific character or a dramatic situation.

The "schmaltzy" reference came from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/2014/dec/19/andrew-lloyd-webber-school-of-rock-musical-broadway):

> His usual metier may be schmaltzy ballads and epic orchestral songcraft, but Andrew Lloyd Webber is to strap on a Strat and unfurl his devil horns for his next project: a Broadway production of School of Rock.